# Importing media medium setting image gallery / image attachments

Tags: customization, attachments, import, images

I have recently imported an image gallery to a clean WP install as I am deploying the site to a live domain.  I have imported the posts but the images use the medium size for attachements.  I would like to get these all to revert to the settings I had set up in the development install.

Does anyone have a idea on how to change the size on already imported image attachements?

Thanks in advance,

J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/.

Answer (score 0):

take a look on this example, with cropping thumbnails using the native "wp_get_attachment_image"... here goes an example of a image gallery, with cropped thumbnails

http://wpworks.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/image-gallery-with-image-crop/

Best Regards